AWS - Terraform - Error: Provider configuration not present
Facing below issue while upgrading nodejs, we followed this Terraform - refactoring modules: Error: Provider configuration not present page but still issue persistent.

Error: Provider configuration not present
To work with
module.proxy.aws_iam_role.iam_for_abc_lambda
its original provider configuration at
module.proxy.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].virginia is
required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider configuration
is removed while objects created by that provider still exist in the state.
Re-add the provider configuration to destroy
module.proxy.aws_iam_role.iam_for_abc_lambda,
after which you can remove the provider configuration again.

We tried mentioned options in below link:

Terraform - refactoring modules: Error: Provider configuration not present


I don't understand how NodeJS and Terraform are in any way related in your question. Those two technologies are not related in any way as far as I'm aware, so I'm not sure why you mention NodeJS in your question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
